# how to get csv content in eclipse when using BIRT?

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, report, birt

I'm trying to test my BIRT report within the eclipse IDE. 
there are many output formats to choose from (View Report).
i installed the org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.csv and interested in that format.
for all other formats i choose, i get prompted for how i want it to be opened (i guess windows does that). if i choose "View Report as PPT", i get prompted for how i want to open the .ppt. there is always an extension (.pdf, .html, .xls, .doc, etc').
only when i try "View Report as CSV" there is no extension. i only get prompted for how i want to open the file whose name is .
(no extension).
what do i have to do (i have the source code of the plugin) to change the output file name to have the .csv extension and so windows will know to suggest opening it with excel?

i'm using eclipse kepler with BIRT 4.3.0 on windows.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running BIRT on a seperate server, that does not have (.pdf, .html, .xls, .doc, etc') installed on it?

Comment: i'm just testing my report in the eclipse IDE. no server is involved other than some DB server. Using the Birt plugins and the above CSV plugin

Answer (score 0):

BIRT is not supporting CSV as of now. But there are open and commercial plugins to do this. 
Have you try this option : https://github.com/Moujimouja/csv-emitter-birt-plugin